# How I can remove a directory and its contents using perl?

Tags: perl

I have a few sub-folders in the main folder. There is a .txt file in each sub-folder. Firstly the code will create the "results" folder in the main folder. And it will search "Frequencies" word in each .txt and print to a new file (in the results folder) the first three columns including "Frequencies" word.
When I run the code the second time, it should remove the result file. But I get the following error when I run it the second time. How can I remove this directory (results) and its contents? (It will work when you run it firstly)

The error:

```
Undefined subroutine &main::rmtree called at xxx.pl line 9.
```

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Path qw/make_path/;
use Cwd;

my $dir = cwd();
my $check_result_file = "$dir/results/";
rmtree($check_result_file);
```

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: It is the top of the code.

Comment: It's better style just to try the `rmtree` and check whether it succeeded. Somebody might create or remove the directory just after you tested for its existence.

Comment: I am using perl 5.18.2 on Ubuntu. I tried `qw/make_path rmtree/`. Now it gives this error: `BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at xxx.pl`

Comment: And this is why you should always copy and paste the code you're actually running into your question instead of inventing snippets that you didn't actually run. `use File::Path qw/make_path/;` only exports `make_path`; if you also want to export `rmtree`, change the `use` statement to `use File::Path qw/make_path rmtree/;`

Comment: I did that correction.When you run it the second time, it gives this error: `Can't open 'results/freq.txt' for reading: 'No such file or directory' at ./frequency.pl line 43` it means `rmtree` doesn't remove the "results" folder when the code run the second time.

Comment: @perlselami That is a totally different question. Have you tried debugging your script by adding `print` statements to confirm that variables have the values you expect them to? Start there, try to narrow down the issue, and if you still can't figure it out, ask another question.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot thanks. I will try what you said.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot. I pasted this part `my $check_result_file = "$dir/results/";
    if ( -e $check_result_file ) {
    rmtree($check_result_file);
    }` subsequent to` my $dir = cwd();`. Now it works even if you run it the second time. Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use File::Path qw/make_path/;
```

tells File::Path to export `make_path`, overriding the list of subs normally exported (`mkpath` and `rmtree`). If you also want want to export `rmtree`, you'll need to specify it.

```
use File::Path qw( make_path rmtree );
```

---

Technically, you could also use the following:

```
use File::Path; 
use File::Path qw( make_path );
```

However, I consider it a good practice to explicitly list all the sub I import, so I strongly favour the first solution I provided.

---

By the way, the versions of File::Path that have `make_path` also have `remove_tree`. `remove_tree` is preferred in favour of `rmtree`.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the semicolon at the end of your `use` line:

```
use File::Path;
              ^ add this
```

Comment: It was a typo. I edited it. But the problem is not that

Comment: Actually, it was. The result of `my $check_folder = "$dir/work";` was passed to `File::Path->import`, overriding the default export list. By adding the semi-colon, the default export list is used, exporting `mkpath` and `rmtree`.

Comment: Without the semicolon, wouldn't he have gotten a syntax error?

Comment: @Barmar, No. One of the syntaxes of `use` is `use Module LIST;`, and `LIST` is a comma-separated list of zero or more expressions, and `my $check_folder = "$dir/work"` is an expression.

Answer (score 0):

Two Things, first, as jwodder mentioned, your missing a semicolon at the end of your use line:

```
use File::Path; <--
```

Second, when checking for a directory, your going to want to use -d rather than -e. -d will check for the existence of a directory, while -e will check for existence of a file. You will also want to do a check against the condition.

```
if ( -d $check_folder)
{ //dostuff }
else
{ //do other stuff}
```

or a unix variant (assuming you do the proper checks for folder to exist first)

```
my $result = system("rm -rf $check_folder);
```

Comment: What does any of this have to do with fixing an undefined function error?

Comment: The very first fix, mentioned by jwodder, should've fixed that error. Should I ignore the fact that his code is incorrect in what he is trying to do?

Comment: If he knows a priori that it will always be a directory if it exists, then there's no difference between `-e` and `-d`.

Comment: He said, "If it exists, that means it is not empty". To me that also implies that it's known to be a directory.

Comment: Sorry, if you can clarify, I'm still not understanding what the issue is? I've always use -d for directory and -f for files.

Comment: The issue is you think there's an issue, and suggesting unwarranted changes as result.

Comment: I edited it like `File::Path qw/make_path/, qw/rmtree/;` but it still gives the same error.

Comment: Yes. Because when I run my code firstly, it creates "work "directory. When I run it second times, the code should remove it.

Answer (score 0):

For windows without 'rm', you can execute on the system.

```
$dir = "C:/somepath/path";
$del_directory = "\@RD /S /Q \"$dir\"";
$exec_del = `$del_directory`;
```

- @RD, is remove directory
- /S, removes all directories and files in the
  directory, including subdirectories.
- /Q, quite mode